# Passing variable from template to ts file in Angular when clicking button

Tags: angular, button, binding, click

I have a component with a getter function which iterates through an object using forEach. In my html file, I am able to access these variables easily. The trouble I'm having is when I want to use a button to fire another function, in which I need to pass one of the variables. although I can access this variable, when I try to pass it in my click function, it remains undefined. I'm quite new at this, so forgive me if the question isn't worded clearly.

here is my code:
my function in my service1 file

```
 viewCompanyIngredients(companyId: number): Observable<Ingredient[]> {
    return this.http.get<Ingredient[]>(`${this.baseUrl}viewCompanyIngredients/${companyId}`, this.httpOptions);
  }
```

my function in my service2 file

```
 addIngredientsToProduct(productId: number, ingredientId: number)  : Observable<Product[]> {
    const body = `ingredient_id=${ingredientId}`;
    return this.http.post<Product[]>(`${this.baseUrl}addIngredientsToProduct/${productId}`, body, this.httpOptions);
  }
```

my ts file

```
import {Component, Inject, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from "@angular/material";
import {ProductService} from "../../../../models/services/product.service";
import {Ingredient} from "../../../../models/ingredient";
import {IngredientService} from "../../../../models/services/ingredient.service";



@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact-add-ingredients-to-products',
  templateUrl: './contact-add-ingredients-to-products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact-add-ingredients-to-products.component.scss']
})
export class ContactAddIngredientsToProductsComponent implements OnInit {
  productId: number;
  ingredientId: number;
  ingredients: Ingredient[];

  displayIngredientColumns: string[] = ['ingredientName', 'ingredientEvalStatus', 'ingredientEvalDate', 'vendorName', 'addThisIngredient'];


  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ContactAddIngredientsToProductsComponent>,
              @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) data,
              private productService: ProductService, private ingredientService: IngredientService) {

              this.productId = data.productId;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.viewCompanyIngredients();
  }

  addIngredientsToProduct(productId, ingredientId) {
    console.log(this.ingredientId)
    this.productService.addIngredientsToProduct(this.productId, this.ingredientId).subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res);

    })
}


  viewCompanyIngredients(): void {
    this.ingredientService.
    viewCompanyIngredients(0).subscribe(
      (res) => {
        if (res[0]) {
          this.ingredients = [];
          res.forEach((item) => {
            item = new Ingredient(item);
            this.ingredients.push(item);
          });
        } else {
          console.warn(res);
        }
        console.log(this.ingredients);
      }
    );
  }

  closeDialog() {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }



}
```

my html file

```
<button mat-stroked-button color="secondary" [ngStyle]="{'margin':'1rem 2rem'}" (click)="closeDialog()">Back</button>


<div  *ngIf="ingredients" class="table">
  <h3 matColumnDef="title">Ingredients</h3>
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="ingredients"  class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="ingredientName">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let ingredient"> {{ingredient.ingredientName}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="ingredientEvalStatus">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Status </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let ingredient"><div *ngIf="ingredient.ingredientEvalStatus == 1">&#10004;</div><div *ngIf="ingredient.ingredientEvalStatus == 0">&#10008;</div></td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="ingredientEvalDate">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Last evaluated</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let ingredient"> {{ingredient.ingredientEvalDate}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="vendorName">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Vendor </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let ingredient"> {{ingredient.vendorName}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="ingredientNote">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Comment</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let ingredient"> {{ingredient.ingredientNote}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="addThisIngredient">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Add This Ingredient </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let ingredient">

        <button mat-stroked-button
                (click)="addIngredientsToProduct(productId, ingredient.ingredientId)">Add This Ingredient</button>
      </td>
     </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayIngredientColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayIngredientColumns;"
        [ngClass]="{'green': row.ingredientEvalStatus==1, 'red': row.ingredientEvalStatus==0}"></tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div *ngIf="!ingredients">
  <h1>This company has no ingredients!</h1>
</div>
```

you'll notice I passed in a variable from another component, and passing it in the click function. This works. The function addIngredientstoProduct also works if I pass an actual number instead of this.ingredientId. How can I access ingredient.id from the template, and pass it in the function addIngredientsToProduct when clicking the button. I've tried so many things but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Can you make a reproduction of your problem in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)? I can not really see where your problem is.

Comment: I think you are passing ingredient.ingredientId as a parameter, but the component has no property named ingredient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign the parameter of the click event handler to `this.ingredientId` and only then inspect its value and pass it to the service:

```
  addIngredientsToProduct(productId, ingredientId) {
    // ADD THIS LINE
    this.ingredientId = ingredientId;
    console.log(this.ingredientId);
    this.productService.addIngredientsToProduct(this.productId, 
    this.ingredientId).subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res);

    })
```